# Powershell script to update a column for a given list item/site page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, pnp-powershell

I have a powershell script that uses a variable $pages (containing all my publishing sites in a library) in a foreach, converts them from classic pages to modern pages and export them to a external library in a different site under the same tenant.

```
foreach($page in $pages)
 { 
Write-Host "Modernizing " $page.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"] "..."

$modernPage = ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage -Identity $page -PublishingPage -Overwrite -TargetWebUrl https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/

Write-Host "Done" -ForegroundColor Green

 }
```

It works, but the new pages does not have the same metadata as the modern site, so my idea is to manually extract the metadata from a column ("category") from the classic pages and add them to a column with the same name for the newly created site.

So in the foreach loop - for every page it will create a new page/list item in the external library (done), and also set a value for a specific column for that new list item with a value based on the specific page/classic page in the loop (not done).The new page has the same name as the classic pages and can be used to identify that specific page. Is it possible?

Example/Pseudo code would be:

Convert to modern page from $page, get the new list item with $page.name, update its column "category" from $page.category:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an older version of PnP-PowerShell, you may have to perform an update, but as of the **February 2019** release, `ConvertTo-PnPClientSidePage` supports the switch parameter `-CopyPageMetadata` to do exactly that without need to write any additional code to loop through metadata values.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/convertto-pnpclientsidepage?view=sharepoint-ps